# tomcat 7 shows compile error in a hello world jsp

Tags: linux, jsp, servlets, tomcat7

Please have a look at the info

•   **Objective:** 
To run a JSP page which calls a java class, both residing on tomcat server

•**Environment** 
**Server environment:** Linux
**Server:** Tomcat7.0.27
**IDE:** none

•**JSP (all it does is display a string)**

```
<%@page import="HelloWorld.HelloWorld" %>  
<HTML>  
<HEAD>  
<TITLE>Hello World/TITLE>  
</HEAD>  
<BODY>  
<H1>Hello World</H1>  
String is: <%= HelloWorld.HelloWorld.display() %>  
</BODY>  
</HTML>
```

•**JSP location**:TOMCAT/webapps/hello/hello.jsp

•**Java class(all it does is return a string)**
package HelloWorld;

```
public class HelloWorld {  
public static String display() {  
 return "Hello World!"; // Display the string.  
   }  
}
```

•**Java class location:** TOMCAT/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.class 
•**Java class compile action:** javac -classpath TOMCAT/lib/servlet-api.jar:. -d /home/user/ HelloWorld.java

**•WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1252"?>  
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'>  
<web-app>  
<display-name>hello</display-name>  
<description>no description</description>  
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>  
<display-name>hello</display-name>  
<description>no description</description>  
<jsp-file>/hello.jsp</jsp-file>  
</servlet>  
<session-config>  
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>  
</session-config>  
</web-app>
```

•**Actions:** 
o   Copy java class to directory 
o   Clean TOMCAT/work directory 
o   Shutdown TOMCAT 
o   Startup TOMCAT 
o   Open server:8080/hello/hello.jsp

•**Issue:** 
HTTP Status 500 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: **Unable to compile class for JSP**: An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file **The import HelloWorld cannot be resolved** An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /hello.jsp HelloWorld cannot be resolved `5: </HEAD> 6: <BODY> 7: <H1>Hello World</H1> 8: String is : <%= HelloWorld.HelloWorld.display() %> 9: </BODY> 10: </HTML>` 
Stacktrace:org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)

There is no syntax error in calling PackageName.ClassName.StringReturningMethod() in JSP 
The class is in package folder.

What is causing it?

Thanks,

Comment: Whoa, uppercased HTML, *Scriptlets*, CP1252 XML encoding and a Servlet 2.3 compatible web.xml. All signs from how JSP/HTML development is (badly) done more than a decade ago. Are you absolutely positive that you're reading the right and up to date tutorials/resources when learning JSP/HTML? Start at our JSP wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the class name is equal to the package name.
There is a name clash since you are importing the package and you are also using the fqn of the class when invoking the *display()* method.

So, you imported *HelloWorld.HelloWorld* and then you try to do *HelloWorld.HelloWorld.display()*. Java is taking the first part of ***HelloWorld***.HelloWorld.display as the class that you have imported and then tries to look for a static member called *HelloWorld* in that class.

Long story short, either remove the import (since you are using the fqn) or do not use the fqn when calling *display()*.

Best Regards,

Comment: did both.....
new JSP:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <H1>Hello World</H1>
  String is: <%= HelloWorld.display() %>
 </BODY>
</HTML>


new response:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /hello.jsp
HelloWorld cannot be resolved
4:  </HEAD>
5:  <BODY>
6:   <H1>Hello World</H1>
7:   String is: <%= HelloWorld.display() %>
8:  </BODY>
9: </HTML>

Comment: If you don't use the fqn, then you must import the class.

Comment: Here http://ubuntuone.com/3YBT0E50Ga62Z643NeFu1d you can find an example I've created. In the webapp you have 2 jsp files: index.jsp fails with the same error you are getting and index1.jsp works fine.

Best Regards